how to ignore get level in priority command
I want to receive offer without priority and i want to ignore my level for that
.method public final getLevel()I
    .registers 2

    .line 1
    iget v0, p0, Lcom/snappbox/offering/common/domain/model/OfferPriority;->level:I

    .line 3
    return v0
.end method


The code you have posted seems to be Smali code, most likely decompiled from an Android app, therefore I understand the java tag, but why have you also use the javascript tag? Anyway your post is too short to understand what you are trying to do, especially as you don't describe anything about the run-time environment, thus the app this code belongs to.

Yeah an app like uber gives offers with priority base level or values i don't know , but i want to remove level to get offer first

Then you start first with the basic APK manipulation checK. If you decompile and recompile + resign it with apktool does the recompiled app work at all? If that isn't the case you don't have to start modifying it.
